# React Navigation - Open Drawer from Other Tab Screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using **React Navigation 5** for my React Native project. I have a **drawer navigator** nested in **tab navigator**.

It looks like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="DrawerStack" component={DrawerStack} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen3Stack" component={Screen3Stack} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Where **DrawerStack** is just a Drawer Navigator with bunch of screens.

My question is, what is the simplest way to open the drawer with a button on Screen2 or Screen3?

Comment: Have you tried `navigation.openDrawe()` ?

Comment: Tried that on Screen2, it will just crash the app. Presumably because of Screen2 does not have Drawer Navigator